# change directory during Install of deb packages for libreoffice 4.2 producing no file found cmd line

Tags: installation, package-management, libreoffice

I am sure I am missing something simple here so apologies in advance if I missed the answered somewhere else.

I am relatively new to linux, have had ubuntu 12.04.4  lts installed for about 2 years now.   Now I want to get in under the hood and actualy understand the OS.

So I decided to update libreoffice to ver.4.2.  I uninstalled the previous copy of Libreoffice following the instructions on [Libreoffice.net](http://www.libre-software.net/how-to-install-libreoffice-on-ubuntu-linux-mint/%22) .

next I downloaded the tar.gz file to download directory, then extracted it within the download directory.

Next, I went to change directory before installing the deb package.

and here is where the problem occurs. I get as a result

```
 bash: cd: /home/kevindv/Downloads/LibreOffice_4.2.0.x_Linux_x86-64_deb/DEBS: No such   
 file or directory
```

I tried typing it in, copy and paste with the middle-click mouse button - both get the same result.

thanks in advance for your help in this matter. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The directory isn't actually called LibreOffice_4.2.0.x_Linux_x86-64_deb, but 4.2.0.4. Not to rub it in, but if you had followed the instructions, this wouldn't have been a problem :)

«`(No need to write everything: use Tab ↹ to autocomplete the command line, or copy and paste with the middle-click mouse button)`»

So, everything is fine and you've done everything correct, except either copy/pasting or entering the complete filename rather than using Tab to complete it for you. :)

Comment: HI Jo, no feel free to rub it in...the simplest mistakes are the hardest to spot ;-) I am here to learn so no worries - thanks for your answer :-)

Comment: ok - I managed to change the directory :-) now I am in ~/Downloads/LibreOffice_4.2.0.4_Linux_x86-64_deb. So to install I use sudo dpkg -i *.deb with * as the package name - yes? because when I do I get errors - I am sure this has to do with being in the directory but I do not know the proper command to install - help once more ;-)

Comment: I'd need to know what errors you get. That should be correct. It means you want to install all the deb packages in that directory. Many things can happen, for instance if you're already installing something using a different tool.